Extract large 7z nested archives using pipe
I have a large password-protected 7z archive that contains another password-protected 7z archive, structured as follows:
OuterArchive.7z (200GB)
    └── InnerArchive.7z (200GB)
        ├── SomeFile.ext (1GB)
        └── ...

The sizes of the archives are extremely large (over 200GB), and I don't have enough free space to extract the entire archive as a file. Therefore, I am trying to use standard I/O pipes to extract only the requested file with the following command:
7z x OuterArchive.7z -so InnerArchive.7z -ppass1 | 7z x -si -so -ppass2 SomeFile.ext

Is this command correct (since it doesn't work), and is it even possible to execute such a thing since the file size exceeds the device's RAM (16GB)?

UPDATE:
Here is the result of the command:
ERROR: 
Can not open the file as archive

E_NOTIMPL

You can see the first part of command is working:
┌──(user㉿dhcppc4)-[~/Desktop/x]
└─$ 7z x OuterArchive.7z -so InnerArchive.7z -ppass1 | head -n 1 | hexdump -C
00000000  37 7a bc af 27 1c 00 04  5f 0f 51 b0 a3 61 2f 29  |7z..'..._.Q..a/)|
00000010  1d 00 00 00 27 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 6f a6 f5 15  |....'.......o...|
00000020  a3 8c 32 aa 06 f8 aa c7  92 b0 42 a1 01 0c 66 a3  |..2.......B...f.|
00000030  77 09 6c c3 f9 da 72 28  20 d0 b6 ac 0b b8 ed fc  |w.l...r( .......|
...

So something must be wrong in this part: 7z x -si -so -ppass2 SomeFile.ext

"since it doesn't work" -- besides not producing the expected file, what other symptoms it exposes? Does it report an error?

"Is this command correct (since it doesn't work), and is it even possible to execute such a thing since the file size exceeds the device's RAM (16GB)?" this statment summed up your answer if it exceeds memory you have,you can't run the command and extract. you need alternate way to extract it basically extracting twice by somehow managing the space in your device.

@axiac , It simply says: "ERROR:  Can not open the file as archive  E_NOTIMPL". please see the UPDATE for more info.

@nabinsademba Oh, Could you please check the UPDATE too. I thought 7z loads data chunk by chunk on the RAM, So the first part (7z x OuterArchive.7z -so InnerArchive.7z -ppass1) streams data correctly, but it cannot execute the second part (after the pipe) right?

try  this:
mkfifo temp_pipe;
7z x OuterArchive.7z -so -ppass1 > temp_pipe &
7z x -si -ppass2 SomeFile.ext < temp_pipe;
rm temp_pipe
, what did you get?

@nabinsademba , [3] 29609 \ 7z Version \ Extracting archive:  ERROR:  Can not open the file as archive  E_NOTIMPL Can't open as archive: 1 Files: 0 Size:0 Compressed: 0 \ [3]  + broken pipe 7z x OuterArchive.7z -so -ppass1 > temp_pipe

It's not clear to me reading up on 7z online whether it can be used to memory-efficiently decompress streams like that.  I wouldn't assume it can't though.  I suggest you create a test 7z - in - 7z archive with a small file and make sure you have the command right.  One thing I see, is that 7z x -si -so appears to set -so standard output but then also provides a SomeFile.ext that seems redundant

@erik258 I created a small nested archive, same error. SomeFile.ext is the name of a sub-file for InnerArchive.7z.

Can you compress InnerArchive as InnerArchive.tar.gz ?

[so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

@Barmar You're right.

@Philippe These archives are previously generated and I don't have access directly to InnerArchive.

Apparently this action is not supported. (cf. E_NOTIMPL).
See: https://superuser.com/questions/1509609/combined-decryption-and-unzipping-of-a-file

The answer from Igor Pavlov (the creator of 7-zip) is:

7-zip needs "seek" operation for 7z archives. So you can't use -si to extract from 7z archive.

This was dated 2016-03-30. My tests and the changelog indicate the statement is still valid in 2019.


It might be possible to mount the external 7z archive as a filesystem so that 7z can have the seekable file it needs.
Some projects that appear to support this using FUSE are:

ratarmount - https://github.com/mxmlnkn/ratarmount
fuse-archive - https://github.com/google/fuse-archive
archivefs - https://lib.rs/crates/archivefs

Using a web-server as a helper:

httpfs2 - https://sourceforge.net/projects/httpfs/files/httpfs2/

cf. Get a listing of a 7zip file on a remote HTTP server


httpdirfs - https://github.com/fangfufu/httpdirfs

Uses temporary files, so probably no good for the use-case of the question:

fuse3-p7zip - https://github.com/andrew-grechkin/fuse3-p7zip

Older, possibly non-working, projects include:

fuse-7z - https://github.com/exmakhina/fuse-7z
fuse-7z-ng - https://github.com/kedazo/fuse-7z-ng


ps. You'd be better off investing in an external drive. I don't know how much they cost where you are, but here in UK, 1TB SSD costs less than a meal out at a not-very-expensive restaurant.

nice sleuthing.  So 7z cannot efficiently operate on a stream

You can try this approach.

Create a dummy file.
fallocate -l 1G innerBigFile1

Compress with 7z
7z a innerBigFile1.7z innerBigFile1

Add the someText.txt to innerBigFile1.7z
7z a innerBigFile1.7z someText.txt

Add innerBigFile1.7z to outerBigFile.7z
7z a outerBigFile.7z innerBigFile1.7z

View inside the 7z archive
7z l outerBigFile.7z

Extract someText.txt from outrBigFile.7z without creating a temporary file due to space contraints.
7z x -so outerBigFile.7z innerBigFile1.7z | 7z x -si -so -y -ttar someText.txt > someTextNew.txt

x : Extract from archive

-so : extract to standard output

-si : input from standard input (output of first command )

-y : say yes!

-ttar : force output to TAR




Hope this helps!

The first part (creating files) was not relevant since I'm already trying to extract a previously created archive, and my archives are password protected. But I tried your last part of the answer like this: 7z x -so OuterArchive.7z InnerArchive.7z -ppass1 | 7z x -si -so -y -ttar -ppass2 SomeFile.ext which prompts with nothing, I couldn't see the use for -ttar tho, when removing it same error pops up.

@behrad your are right, Let me dig deeper.
